# Loading RData files from my own directory

Tags: r, rstudio

How do i do to load RData files from the same directory of file .R on RSTudio?

For example, the line:

`load('teste.RData')`

it returns error..

> Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : 
>         directory not found

That does not happen when i write the path of the folder

`load('~/Downloads/teste.RData')`

Why does it happen? How do I do to load the file without write the complete path?

Comment: `getwd()` will tell you what the current working directory is and that is where it will attempt to load `'teste.RData'` from.

Comment: And the partner function `setwd()` will allow you to change it. If you are `source()`-ing an R file, there is a `chrdir=` parameter that allows you to automatically change the current directory to the same as the .R file during sourcing.

Comment: @MrFlick i load the R file on the RStudio. How do i change the currect directory to the same as the .R file?

Comment: I don't use Rstudio. If this is only an Rstudio, question, then you can remove the R tag.

Comment: This is a `getwd()`, `setwd()` (R) question, has nothing to do with RStudio. I suggest the tag be removed. One way is to set a working dir of the script and use that (relative) path, or, what MrFlick said, sourcing the file with a temporary working directory.

Comment: Take a look at the `Session->Set Working Directory` menu but you'll be better off learning the core R way of doing it via the `*wd()` functions.